How to share applications between multiple OSs?
My goal is to have a triple monitor setup, each running a different OS (Linux, Windows and MacOS) and have mouse/keyboard sharing using something like Synergy as well as moving app windows from one to the other (i.e have Windows running a game and move that app's window to the Linux desktop).
The idea is that since I use all three systems, I might as well have a seamless integration between them. I am open to running all three systems on one really powerful device (Linux running VMs for macOS and Windows) and to having three independent PCs each with one OS.
I prefer Wayland over X11, but I can use X if it would have easier compatibility for this type of thing. I have some minimal experience with programming so I can edit some configs and setup up a series of programs to make this work, but I can't completely create the entire thing from scratch.
Is this even possible? Maybe X11 Forwarding? Let me know what you guys suggest. I appreciate anything you have to offer.

That is something I'll definitely want with this setup and it's something that I can achieve with only a little work, but the big issue is being able to drag an apps window from one OS to the other as if they were one system (obviously only one system would actually be running the app, but it would "share" the window similar to how synergy does the mouse/keyboard)

I would assume that for it to work, it would require an app installed on all three to manage X11 forwarding or something similar to share the app similar to how Synergy works.

I agree with Linux as the base OS, and VM the other OSs. The trouble being the big three OSs are sworn enemies.  Windows does not work well others, intentionally.  As does macOS. Finding common ground between the three is always a struggle.
VirtualBox has an app mode. Which allows you to run apps in windows, making it seem like you are running three OSs seamlessly.
VirtualBox also has folder mounting. But what filesystem do you choose as a common filesystem. If you're running games in windows. Do the VM video drivers passthrough at speeds to run a game at acceptable speeds?
The nice thing with VirtualBox is it's FOSS software (free and open-source software). So you can test this setup for free.
Good luck, I think this a great exercise to learn the limits of Windows and macOS. And dealing with those issues.

Licensing is an issue, but if your hardware is compatible, you can run MacOs in a VM.  https://www.xda-developers.com/how-install-macos-virtualbox/
